# Include JUnit like reports in SONAR

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to include SoapUI and utPLSQL JUnit generated reports when doing the Sonar Analysis.

I can successfully include results in Java and .NET projects, but in other type of projects even when I have found ways to create XML formatted output and store it in Jenkins I do not find a way to pass those reports to sonar to be included in the dashboard of the project.

I tried several properties to define in the sonar runner, but always with no luck (sonar.dynamicAnalysis, sonar.surfire.reportPaths, sonar.junit.reportPaths)

I read in some Sonar development plugins that depending on the language detected those coverage test files are just ignored, so I am wondering if there is another option different than running a multilanguage sonar project with a dummy Java class or something like that.

Thanks in advance for your time,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at the [Generic Test Data](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data) documentation of sonarqube if you are on version 6.2+. Below that version you could check out this plugin [Generic Test Coverage](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage), but i am not sure what this is actually covering.

There is a way to provide such information, in a generic format. This also works for coverage.